# Particle System (Collection) picking children of objects in collection

Tags: particles, hair, parent, collections

I want to create a forest in blender and created two tree models. I want the trees to be randomly placed on a plane by a particle system. Thats why I put them into a collection. However, the particle system uses all the children objects of each tree, for example the trunk. So I want to know how to tell the particle system to use each tree as a whole.

Here is an image of the collection:

[image]

Here is an image of the current particle system:

[image]

I enabled "Whole Collection" in the render tab, but then, like the name says, all the objects of the collection where placed in the same pattern across the plane - that is not what I want. I want the trees to be randomly placed individually as a whole. Did I do something wrong with parenting the objects?

I hope you can help me! Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial will help you...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLw0HwphXO0&list=RDCMUCOKHwx1VCdgnxwbjyb9Iu1g&index=7

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So I need to use the Geometry Nodes or is there another way?

Comment: I think GN is the most easy and clear way.

Comment: Ok thanks! To me it seems more complicated - I am a beginner and I have never used it before, but I will try.

Comment: I managed to do it! It was pretty straight forward. Thank you.